# In Linux How to find file names starts with zi and exactly 8 character in length

Tags: linux

How can I find files with exactly 8 characters in length and it starts with zi
Example names:

```
/home/ziDZaTxG
/home/ziIbLnaG
/home/ziQxgoXh
/home/ziw2NOBD
/home/zixqlM2S
```

> find /home/ -name "zi*"

This works and find it correctly, but not able to count the 8 characters match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the question mark wildcard, which matches exactly one character.

```
find /home -name "zi??????"
```

Here's an example run:

```
[developer:~/t] $ touch zi1
[developer:~/t] $ touch zi123456
[developer:~/t] $ touch zi1234567
[developer:~/t] $ find . -name "zi??????"
./zi123456
```

You could also choose to use the -regex option to 'find'.

Answer (score 0):

To find the length of filename, you need to remove the path and match only the characters after the last /

Pipe your output to grep command :

```
find /home/ -name "zi*" |grep -P '/.{8}$'
```

-P : To activate perl expression

/. : Go to last /

{8} : 8 Characters

$ : End